# Is my Tor service being middle manned hacked or sec?

Tags: anonymity, security, guard, orbot

Recently I noticed a big change in my orbot log...it starts with these 4 PRE QUESTIONS-

```
tor: PRE: Is binary exec? true
polipo: PRE: Is binary exec? true
obfsclient: PRE: Is binary exec? true
xtables: PRE: Is binary exec? true
```

Also all my circuits are now being built by zwiebelringrexlocus

My circuits no longer seem to be popping around different connections and cities...whats happened?

```
Orbot is starting…
Orbot is starting…
Waiting for control port...
tor: PRE: Is binary exec? true
polipo: PRE: Is binary exec? true
obfsclient: PRE: Is binary exec? true
xtables: PRE: Is binary exec? true
Orbot is starting…
Orbot is starting…
updating torrc custom configuration...
success.
Orbot is starting…
Waiting for control port...
Connecting to control port: 54534
SUCCESS connected to Tor control port.
SUCCESS - authenticated to control port.
Starting Tor client… complete.
adding control port event handler
SUCCESS added control port event handler
NOTICE: Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
Local SOCKS port: 9050
NOTICE: Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:55000 
NOTICE: Closing old Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:55000 
Local TransProxy port: 9040
NOTICE: Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400 
NOTICE: Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:49624 
NOTICE: Closing old DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:49624 
Local DNSPort port: 9040
Tor started; process id=8325
updating settings in Tor service
Starting polipo process
Set background service to FOREGROUND
Polipo is running on port:8118
Polipo process id=8328
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
Circuit (1) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus
Circuit (2) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > InRamOnlyNoLogs > mb1
NOTICE: Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
Circuit (3) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > spfTOR1e3 > ArachnideFR1
Circuit (3) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > spfTOR1e3 > ArachnideFR1
Circuit (5) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > redbeantorrelay > esbek1
Circuit (5) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > redbeantorrelay > esbek1
Circuit (4) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > thys2 > lndmvps
Circuit (4) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > thys2 > lndmvps
Circuit (6) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > ceguild2 > Chandler23
Circuit (6) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > ceguild2 > Chandler23
Circuit (8) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > afo2 > krosnovorg
Circuit (8) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > afo2 > krosnovorg
Circuit (7) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > PPTOR0007 > borvo
Circuit (7) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > PPTOR0007 > borvo
Circuit (11) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > Logforme > Anubis
Circuit (10) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > torpidsUKuk22 > wannabe2
Circuit (10) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > torpidsUKuk22 > wannabe2
Circuit (12) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > Cyberpunktor > Chandler02
Circuit (9) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > afo2 > destiny
Circuit (9) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > afo2 > destiny
Circuit (13) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > Mirage > SwartzTorNodeA01x
Circuit (14) BUILT: poiuty1
Circuit (15) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > 1001001de > ethanzuckerman
Circuit (16) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > EBMlover > tortuga2
Circuit (17) BUILT: wtfloki
Circuit (1) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus
Circuit (18) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus
Circuit (14) CLOSED: poiuty1
Circuit (19) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > Unnamed > BeSeeingYou
Circuit (20) BUILT: poiuty1
Circuit (17) CLOSED: wtfloki
Circuit (21) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > conservatorry > TorLand1
Circuit (18) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus
Circuit (20) CLOSED: poiuty1
Circuit (22) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus
Circuit (23) BUILT: wtfloki
Circuit (16) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > EBMlover > tortuga2
Circuit (24) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > Justa4 > BeSeeingYou
Circuit (21) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > conservatorry > TorLand1
Circuit (22) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus
Circuit (23) CLOSED: wtfloki
Circuit (25) BUILT: poiuty1
Circuit (26) BUILT: wtfloki
Circuit (27) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > zwiebelkuchen > destiny
Circuit (27) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > zwiebelkuchen > destiny
Circuit (28) BUILT: zwiebelringrexlocus > Torbob05 > Chandler05
Circuit (24) CLOSED: zwiebelringrexlocus > Justa4 > BeSeeingYou
```

Answer (score 3):

> Also all my circuits are now being built by zwiebelringrexlocus
>   My circuits no longer seem to be popping around different connections and cities... whats happened?

zwiebelringrexlocus is your (new?) guard node. It is normal and by design that you keep using the same guard for a long time.
The 2nd and 3rd node in your circuits are all different. You do still exit from different exits.

I don't use Orbot so I can't comment on whether those permission checks are normal.